# Applying JQuery-UI datepicker in a template before it is added to the DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, templates, backbone.js, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to apply a datepicker every  inside a template, then add that template to the DOM.
I was able to do it by adding the template to the DOM first (using $.each), but I am separating the responsibilities now (using Backbone) and I need it done in that order.
I tried to use replaceWith in the context of my template :

```
$("input[type=date]", template).replaceWith(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({dateFormat : "yy-mm-dd"});
    return this.outerHTML;
});
return Mustache.render(template, this.model.toJson);
```

but template is not updated, and replaceWith only returns an array with my updated inputs. I feel the answer is not far, but I'm stuck here.
I can render the template with Mustache before or after applying the datepickers, this is not a problem.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

`Mustache.render` is going to return some HTML based on the template in `template` and data in `this.model.toJson` (which should be `this.model.toJSON()`, no?). All the jQuery UI stuff and jQuery events are bound to DOM elements, not HTML text so it doesn't matter what you bind to `template`, none of it will survive going through Mustache.

You need to bind everything to the *output* of `Mustache.render`. Something more like this:

```
render: function() {
    var template = ...
    var html = Mustache.render(template, this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.append(html);
    this.$('input[type=date]').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
    return this;
}
```

and then whatever called `render` would `$something.append(v.render().el)`.